# Can you help me identify story about pinball game as suicide machine

Tags: story-identification

It is a probably more than 20 years ago that I came across a story where people were playing a multi-players pinball game. When a player has lost his ball, he was executed.

I'm not completely sure but it seems that players decided to play game voluntary as they already are decided to make a suicide.

The narrator of the story is player that during a game changes his mind about suicide and he is the last player that hasn't lost a ball.

Those are very weak memories of the story that I have read only once and I would like to find out the title and the author of this story.